# Possible to download file with code in class library

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, download

I have a C# Class Library project which inherits a third party solution and then i implement the methods they have provided.

Everything works as expected but one task i am trying to accomplish is to download a file. I have used the below code which i have entered into a class in my project:

```
string fp = "C:\Complete\Path\File.pdf";
FileInfo fi= new FileInfo(fp);

System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=test.pdf");
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fi.Length.ToString());
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.TransmitFile(fi.FullName);
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

- So the file exists (i can get to it).
- I have stepped through the code and no errors.
- The above code works on a page (Asp .Net page).
- In Chrome the file starts downloading then i receive "Failed- Network error".
- In Edge - page cannot be found.

Is there any other way to trigger a file download when the code resides in a Class library?

**Edit 1 (Fiddler)**

HTTP/1.1 504 Fiddler - Receive Failure
Date: Tue, 02 Jan 2018 16:35:40 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: close
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
Timestamp: 16:35:40.226

[Fiddler] ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a complete response for this request. Server returned 408 bytes.

**Edit 2**

```
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = false;
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.TransmitFile(fi.FullName);
    //System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

Comment: have you looked via Fiddler or similar to see what is actually being sent at the http level?

Comment: I just did that. When Fiddler is running i get the info under Edit 1, when i close Fiddler then i get the Network Failed error in Chrome

Comment: Ok a strange one. Looking in Fiddler my localhost address is set to localhost:12345 for the site. This gets a 504 error, but the next entry is localhost:22222 which i dont know where that came from but under the headers > security i see Origin localhost:12345 (the site address where i initiated the download from). Not too sure whats going on here?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `maxRequestLength` (in kb) in config file.

```
<system.web>
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1500000" />
</system.web>
```

Hope that helps

**OR**

Try to set `Buffer = false` and End request using `HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();` unless  `Response.End();`

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = false; 
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.TransmitFile(fi.FullName);    
//System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

Let us know your try

Comment: Sorry this does nothing different. My config file reads <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" enableVersionHeader="false" targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="1500000" fcnMode="Single"/>

Comment: Nope that didnt work either - my code is under edit 2 in case i have misunderstood you

Comment: @Computer may I know file size?

Comment: No more than 1MB

Comment: @Computer have you check server error logs because it shows 504 'Gateway timeout' error